# Area of 2D fractal?

Tags: fractals

Some fractals have a whole fractal dimension, can their measure be calculated?
For example if you start with a tetrahedron of a given size and recursively remove the central octahedron leaving 4 tetrahedrons of half the side length you will end up with a fractal of dimension 2. How does the area of this fractal relate to the size of the original tetrahedron? There is an image of this fractal [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cmglee_Cambridge_Science_Festival_2015_Menger_sponge.jpg).
What if you start with a cube, divide it into eight smaller cubes, remove the four cubes of a given parity and continue recursively [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tlgK.png)?
If you generate the Type 2 Quadratic curve (dimension 1.5) on one plane and a 0.5 dimensional Generalized Cantor Set on the perpendicular axis, produce a plane going through every point in the Cantor set and project the curve on each plane, what is the area of this?

Comment: Hint: at every step, the surface area stays constant.

Comment: I do not mean the _surface_ area of the fractal, I mean the measure of the fractal itself.

Comment: Also, for some similar fractals it does not stay constant.

Comment: Also, if the four top cubes are always kept the final result is a plane with area l^2 (l is the side length of the original cube) but the total area of the cube is 6 l^2, which is much bigger.

Comment: You say "Area" in your question, not "Measure"...also do you mean measure of the fractal or measure of the boundary?

Comment: I mean the measure of the fractal itself, I say area because the fractal dimension is 2.